# ILogger dependency injection issue in .Net6 Azure Functions

Tags: azure, function, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I recently converted .NET 3.1 azure function code to .NET6. the below code in the startup class was working fine , while deploying to Azure as Azure function but after converting to .NET6, We are getting the below error.

> *Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Invalid host services detected. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: The following service registrations did not match the expected services: [Missing] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.FunctionFileLoggerProvider, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null [Missing] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.HostFileLoggerProvider, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.*

startup class code

```cs
public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddCashMatchingService();
        builder.Services.AddDataManagerService();
           
        builder.Services.AddOptions();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(p=>new DebugLoggerProvider());
        builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.ClearProviders()
            .AddSerilog(
                Activator.CreateInstance<LoggerConfiguration>().Enrich
                    .FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
                 "azureStorageConnection-StorageConnection"),
                  (Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel)Enum.Parse(
                     typeof(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel),
              Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Serilog_MinimumLevel")),
              Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Serilog_ContainerName"),
              Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Serilog_StorageFileName"))
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault(),
                TelemetryConverter.Events)
            .CreateLogger()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question

Comment: the one i have added is the right one. This is what i can able to see from Azure function portal.

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file package reference file.

Comment: What you posted is the exception message; not the stack trace. Stack traces are tremendously helpful in finding the cause of such issue.

Comment: do not clear logging providers. For some reason at least one logging provider is required during startup...

Answer (score 0):

Don't clear logging providers as mentioned in the [comment by Loul G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894647/ilogger-dependency-injection-issue-in-net6-azure-functions/77141325#comment135508487_73894647).

I had the same issue. Looks like AZ Functions require these 2 specific logger providers for some unknown reason